# javascript callback confusion between multiple functions

Tags: javascript

```
function A(){
   b()
   c()
}
```

Function c has to be called after function b. 
I know there's a concept in JavaScript called callback.

How do I do it in function b?

```
function b(cb){
//I can't put function c here, because this of c is bound to somewhere and I don't want to mess up.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c()` will always be called after `b()` because you placed it there.

The real question is whether or not `c()` will be called before `b()` is finished.

If `b()` is **not** an async function, then your code is perfect. `c()` will be called once `b()` is finished.

```
function A(){
    b(); // *not* async
    c();
}
```

However, if `b()` is async in nature, you need to provide `c()` as a callback. 
    function A(){
        b(c); // async
    }

```
function b(cb){
    // ...
    cb(); // cb() doesn't need "this"
}
```

Since `c()` is a bound method, you need to also pass the context (`this`) to `b()`.

```
function A(){
    /* extract and save context, somehow */
    b(c, context); // async
}

function b(cb, context){
    // ...
    cb.call(context); // cb() doesn't need "this"
}
```

> I don't want to mess up.

If you don't want to play with context passing, you can use a [`Promise`](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-promises-in-depth).

```
function A(){
    b().then(function() {
        // run "c()" only when "b()" is finished and there were no errors
        c();
    });
}

function b(){
    // ...
    // "b()" is *not* async
    return Promise.resolve();
}

function b(){
    // ...
    // "b()" is async
    var whenDone = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        performAsyncTask(resolve);
    })
    return whenDone;
}
```

But wait, there's more.

If you want bleeding edge tech, you can always use [`async/await`](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await)

```
async function A(){
    await b(); // VOILA! it's that easy
    c();
}
```

---

These are the general basic strategies. Of course, you can try to mix-n-match them or try to figure out something new that suits your needs.

Comment: woah async function is elegant.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use [Promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises) or a callback.

In this case I'd use a callback (as it's a simple use case & promises require crossbrowser checks).

```
function A() {
    b(c); // Pass the function 'c'
}

function c() {
    // Do something else
}

function b(callback) {
    // Do something

    // Run callback
    callback(); // This will run whatever method you passed in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function b(c){
    doSomething();
    c();
}

function a(){
    b(c);
}
```

Comment: Try explaining the example

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding is correct. The notion of the callback is when a function is complete. What you're going to have to do is to ensure that the type of input and make sure it is a function and not something different. Take a look at the following example:

```js
function A()
{
    alert('I am A function');
    b(c);
}

function b(cb)
{
    alert('I am "b" function');
    
    
    /// At the very end, put this code:    
    if (typeof(cb)==='function')
    {
         cb();
    }
}

function c()
{
    alert('I am "c" function');
}



A();
```

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks in JavaScript are functions that are passed as arguments to other functions. This is a very important feature of asynchronous programming, and it enables the function that receives the callback to call our code when it finishes a long task, while allowing us to continue the execution of the code.

```
var callback = function() {
    console.log("Done!");
}

setTimeout(callback, 5000);
```

As you can see, **setTimeout** receives a function as a parameter, this is a callback!

In your case you can do the following:

```
function b(c) {
    c();
}

// calling function b and sending as a parameter an anonymous function
// that will be replaced by the "c" parameter in the "b" function
b(function() {
    console.log("inside c");
});
```

This is almost a closure, just with a little bit more tweaking and you can turn it into one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, let me try to decipher.

If you execute

```
function A() { b(); c() }
function b() { /* b work */ }
function c() { /* c work */}
```

Then `c` will be called after `b` **if by is synchronous**.

In the case b is asynchronous, `c` will be called before `b` completes.
Then you need indeed a callback as a parameter of `b`:

```
function A() { b(c) }
function b(callback) { /* b work */ ; callback() }
function c() { /* c work */ }
```

Yet in modern js, you'd rather use a promise:

```
function A() {
  b().then( function() {
    c()
  } )
}
function b() {
  return new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
    /* b work */
  } )
}
function c() { /* c work */ }
```